# Upload an image to my server without using FTP info in my code?

Tags: php, .net

I have an image  Picture1.jpg

I have made an application in C# that I want it to upload this picture to my server but I don't won't to do that through connecting to FTP in my C# application because I will have to put my FTP login and password inside the code.

So I decided to upload to my server a php file that will receive my image

```
  http://www.example.com/receive.php
```

Then from my C# app, I just do the following :

```
  wc.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.example.com/receive.php?img={IMAGE_AS_TEXT }"));
```

Then all I have to do is to convert back the text to image in PHP and display it in user browser.

How can I convert an image to text in C# and convert it back to image using PHP ?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: use base64MIME for encoding and decoding

Comment: thank you @sqlab , is there any alternative to base64 that doesn't make the file size larger ?

Comment: you could try to zip them first. But your text will always be longer as there are not so many chars as alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for PHP **base64_decode** and
for C# **System.Convert.ToBase64String**
look [Encoding Strings to Base64 in C#](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/)